# Can this differential equation exclusively have periodic solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Can the differential equation
> $$y^{(3)}+2y''+ay'+y=0, \: a\in \mathbb{R} $$
> have exclusively periodic (like $\cos(\omega t)$ and $\sin(\omega t)$) as solutions?

I think the answer is no. I wasn't able to show this rigorously, but I used Maple's "dsolve" command to find the solutions to this differential equation.

It turns out that there is always a term $e^{-t}$ multiplied in the solution making it not a *exclusively* periodic solution. Is there a way to show that this always has to be the case?

Here is an example where I set $a=2$, and you can see the term $e^{-t}$ in the solution.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the characteristic polynomial is real and of degree 3, there will always be a real root. As this can not be $0$ (see constant term), you always get an exponential basis solution.